# Regular Expression for a character attached to a number as "1a"

Tags: java, regex

I need to identify in a selected text the tokens which are composed of an integer and a character as in "2a". The number can be from 1-100 and the letter from a-z with no repetitions. For this it would be safe to have a regular expression to pick them out. Its a concrete example but maybe useful also for others hopefully.

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Can you detail what you have tried? Stack overflow tends to work better when you try something, and other people help you finish your work.

Comment: \d?[a-z] I've tried this but it is completely not right and problem is that regex's are crazy and wild, only a good hunter can hold those beasts.

Comment: `\d+[a-z]` should work.

Comment: isn't `d+` the reg expression meaning 1 or more digits? This would admit 1000. If he really wants to constrain to 1-100 I'm thinking this wouldn't be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier to answer to your question with a sample data. However, for what you stated *'The number can be from 1-100 and the letter from a-z with no repetitions'* you can use a regex like:

```
\b(?:100|[1-9]\d?)[a-z]\b
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/tT8hV5/2)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: @BDays fixed! Thanks for catching that

Comment: Great with the fix but now it misses the last part of the request which is with no repetitions. https://regex101.com/r/tT8hV5/2 You can have a look here to see it picks up repeated values

Comment: @BDays I think OP meant by "no repetitions" the pattern over the letter, for instance `1a` instead of `1aaaa`. Anyway, if OP wants to do what you commented, they could use a capturing group and some logic with maps or sets.

Comment: Actually I referred to both but since repeating numbers just make new numbers its fine if repeated until 100. But for the letter there is no repetition. I'm trying it out, if it works im going to accept it as an answer. thank u

Comment: @erta alright, for that case you can use capturing groups with `\b((?:100|[1-9]\d?)[a-z])\b` and iterate over the matcher storing in a Set the group content